# X-bar tree of the sentence "Why would she not have actually been giving him back the present yesterday?"

Tags: syntax-trees, generative-grammar, x-bar-theory

I'm having trouble with a particular x bar tree. We're mostly using Liliane Haegeman & Jacqueline Guéron's "English Grammar – A Generative Perspective" as our bible, with some adjustments, e.g. DP's instead of naked NP's. I could really use a fresh pair of eyes, and I hope this is the place to find them. Would you generate the tree differently?

[image: x bar tree]

Comment: While questions to *make* trees are OT, questions *about* trees are not. Given the stipulated framework, I assume there is a technically correct answer, either "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Oh, sorry if this question is against the rules. I didn’t knew, if it was.

Comment: If it makes a difference, the main doubts I had was about how you should generate the verb particle here and in general.

Comment: Chill @HrLarsen homework questions like draw me a synatx tree of XYZ sentence and related questions are off topic which does not seem to be the case here. And welcome to Linguistics SE! (:

Comment: @WiccanKarnak, thanks! I'm glad to hear that :)